# export 'default' (imported as 'vue') was not found in 'vue'

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code, quasar

im a beginner in development (vuejs and quasar), i tried to run this code but I have an error "**export 'default' (imported as 'vue') was not found in 'vue'** " in my editor. I tried everything still doesn't work... plz help
I'm trying to remove a task from a list of tasks. one I click on delete button, I have an error **"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'delete') at Store.deleteTask"** in vueTools in chrome.

```Vue-js
import Vue from 'vue'

const state = {
tasks : {
    'ID1':{
        name:'Go to shop',
          completed:false,
          dueDate:'2021/10/29',
          dueTime:'18:02'
    },
    'ID2':{
        name:'Get bananas',
        completed:false,
         dueDate:'2021/10/30',
        dueTime:'18:04'
    },
    'ID3':{
        name:'Get apples',
          completed:false,
          dueDate:'2021/10/31',
          dueTime:'18:06'
    },
}
}

const mutations = {
    updateTask(state, payload) {
        Object.assign(state.tasks[payload.id], payload.updates)
    },
    deleteTask(state, id) {
        Vue.delete(state.tasks, id)

    }

}

const actions = {
    updateTask({commit}, payload){
    commit('updateTask', payload)
    },
    deleteTask({ commit}, id){
        commit('deleteTask', id)
    }
}

const getters = {

    tasks: (state) => {
        return state.tasks
    }
}

export default {
    namespaced: true,
    state,
    mutations,
    actions,
    getters

};
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, what happens if you import Vue from 'vue/dist/vue'?

Comment: You probably have Vue 3 installed, which no longer exports a default. You don't need to use `Vue.delete` in Vue 3 (splice it out by index instead).

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your answers, i find it.
First of all, i tried to use 'splice', however, it doesn't work.

I tried **'import Vue from 'vue/dist/vue'** I get an error **'vue was not found in vue'**, so i followed some advice, i reinstall vue with npm. And finally it works.

So, i find 2 solutions after reinstalling vue in my system

**import Vue from 'vue/dist/vue'
Vue.delete(state.tasks, id)**
this time it worked

and also

**delete state.tasks[id]**

works without any importation

**Thank you all, guys.**